# Custom Firebird ODBC Connection String for Sharepoint Designer

Tags: string, connection, odbc, sharepoint-2013, firebird

I am trying to connect a firebird database as a Sharepoint Data Source in Sharepoint Designer. So far I have used numerous connection strings and had no luck.

I keep getting the same server error message.

The error is: Server Error: An error occurred while retrieving the list of Databases from //Server Name: The Web Server Cannot connect to the specified data source because the query may contain errors, the data source may be unavailable or configured improperly, or your web site is behind a proxy server or firewall.

Does anyone know what connection string I should use for a firebird ODBC connection string into sharepoint Designer?

Comment: `Provider=LCPI.IBProvider.3;Data Source=MyCompName;Persist Security Info=True;Password=MyPasswor;User ID=MyUserId;Location=MyCompName:d:\database\MyDatabase.fdb;ctype=win1251;auto_commit=True;support_odbc_query=True;support_square_delim_name=1`

Comment: Please post the connection strings you tried, and the errors you get.

Comment: I tried using the String that Val provided but I still got the same error. The error is: Server Error: An error occurred while retrieving the list of Databases from //Server Name: The Web Server Cannot connect to the specified data source because the query may contain errors, the data source may be unavailable or configured improperly, or your web site is behind a proxy server or firewall.           I substituted the actual server name with "//Server Name"    For the password and User ID: I used the "GONE, fishing" credentials which is what I used to set up the ODBC and for jasper reports.

Comment: Provider=LCPI.IBProvider.3;Data Source=//Server Name;Persist Security Info=True;Password=fishing;
User ID=GONE;Location=//Server Name/C:\Program Files\Fishbowl\database\data\Test.FDB;
ctype=win1251;auto_co‌​mmit=True;support_odbc_query=True;support_square_delim_name=1